# How would I sort a list of strings descending order, then ascending order (if tied)?

Tags: java, sorting

OK this question may make you say "What??" but ill try to give a bit of context.
I'm working on a program that reads a *plaintext* file , sorts the strings in the file by descending order by number of times that word occurred , then for the words that have the same number of times it occurred, I have to sort those words in ascending alphabetical order...

Right now I have an arraylist called 'words' that contains every word in a text file I open. So how do I go about sorting it in descending order by number of occurred words and then ascending alphabetical order if there is a tie in occurence?

So if I had a list that was:

```
[a, a, a, a, b, c, c, c, c, d, d, e, e, e, e, e]
```

My output list after the sort would be:

```
e : 5
a : 4  // notice the words that occur 4 times are alphabetical sorted
c : 4
d : 2
b : 1
```

Comment: By writing a `Comparator` with that behavior.

Comment: `list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, Collectors.counting())).entrySet().sorted(Entry.comparingByValue().reversed().thenComparing(Entry.comparingByKey())).collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, LinkedHashMap::new))`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch so if I wrote a Comparator, wouldn't I have to add a count variable inside of it to keep count of the words that occur multiple times?

Comment: There's nothing to count in a `Comparator`: you're given two items `a` and `b`; you say whether `a` is less than, equal to, or greater than `b`.    There's nothing more to a `Comparator` than that.

Comment: @KevinAnderson Thats what I thought, if a Comparator only compares two Objects, theres no way for me to use it in this case

Comment: Of course there is. You just need to pre-compute the counts to use in the comparison.

Comment: Well, you don't just use a `Comparator` alone.  You give it to a sort method along with your collection of data to be sorted and the result is a sorted collection.

Comment: @KevinAnderson Ah, I see. I do already have a selection sort code that can be passed an ArrayList and a Comparator, so if I make a comparator that compares two Strings of the ArrayList, the selection sort should automatically sort the tied occurences in alphabetical order right?

Comment: The selection sort will sort the `ArrayList` in whatever order the `Comparator` imposes.  It all depends on how you write the `Comparator`.

Answer (score 0):

From your question.

> sorts the strings in the file by descending order by number of times that word occurred , then for the words that have the same number of times it occurred, I have to sort those words in ascending alphabetical order...

It means that

First, you need to get a **distinct** list of word and count the occurrence of each word, this can be achieved using a [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Second, order the distinct list of word first by the number of occurrence descending, then by alphabetical ascending, this can be achieved by implementing a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and use [Collections.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) method.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class SortOccurrence {
    Map<String, Integer> wordToOccurenceMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    SortOccurrence(List<String> words) {
        // Count occurrence for each word
        for (String word : words) {
            if (!wordToOccurenceMap.containsKey(word)) {
                wordToOccurenceMap.put(word, 0);
            }
            wordToOccurenceMap.put(word, wordToOccurenceMap.get(word) + 1);
        }
    }

    List<String> getSortResult() {
        List<String> distinctWords = new ArrayList<String>(wordToOccurenceMap.keySet());
        Collections.sort(distinctWords, new OccurrenceComparator());
        List<String> sortResult = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String distinctWord : distinctWords) {
            sortResult.add(distinctWord + " : " + wordToOccurenceMap.get(distinctWord));
        }
        return sortResult;
    }

    public class OccurrenceComparator implements Comparator<String> {

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            if (!wordToOccurenceMap.containsKey(o1) || !wordToOccurenceMap.containsKey(o2)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("word not occur");
            }
            // if occurrence same, compare the string
            if (wordToOccurenceMap.get(o1).compareTo(wordToOccurenceMap.get(o2)) == 0) {
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }
            // compare by occurrence, '-' for descending
            return -wordToOccurenceMap.get(o1).compareTo(wordToOccurenceMap.get(o2));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> input = Arrays.asList(
                new String[] { "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e" });

        SortOccurrence sortOccurence = new SortOccurrence(input);
        System.out.println(sortOccurence.getSortResult());
    }
}
```